# Javascript alert is not displaying in the current tab on selnium RC

Tags: selenium

Selenium RC:

```
selenium.runScript("javascript{alert('hi')}");
```

[image]

See the screen-shot. Alert box  must show in tab2 but it is in tab1. So, any one give an answer how to show a alert box in tab2?

Answer (score 0):

1. Just try to switch tab where you want to see the alert
2. Then Execute your alert popup code